# Nuxtjs how to use an Api url and bypass the CORS policy

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I try to enable CORS to bring JSON data from a PHP microservice located at the `api` folder at the root of the NuxtJs project.

The JSON is being served by the PHP microservice as expected.

I follow the instructions at [this link](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/) :

At nuxtjs.config file in the modules section i just add @nuxtjs/proxy:

```
    modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'            
  ],
```

And at the end of the nuxtjs.config file i just add

```
 },

  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost/myapi/index.php',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api' : '/'
        }
      }
  }
```

And at the index.vue file i just add:

```
Axios.get('/api')
```

I did not see the json data after theses steps.

How can i configure Nuxt.Js to accept CORS and properly consume external API´S ?

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/

Comment: share the request response, maybe the error is in the api itself

Comment: It works, just clear the cache and run npm run dev again. There is a command line to rebuild clearing the cache ?